# 2005 Honda CR-V wiper blade sizes

Tags: honda, windshield-wipers, crv

What are the correct wiper blade sizes for a 2005 Honda CR-V (EX, if it matters)?

[WiperBladesUSA.com](https://www.wiperbladesusa.com/wiper-blades/honda/cr-v/2005) shows **21" / 20" / 10"** and [EZWipers.com](https://www.ezwipers.com/wipers/Honda/CR-V/2005) says they are **21" / 19" / 12"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Trico brand exact original replacement" lists 21" drivers side, 20" passenger side and 10" for the rear. You will find some variation between brands. This is sometimes done to limit the number of sizes that need to be stocked. It is not uncommon for a wiper an inch longer or shorter to be listed and work without any issues. As @Paulster2 has stated as long as the wiper stays entirely on the glass longer might be better.

Comment: These numbers are the OEM lengths per the Honda parts catalog.

Comment: I own a 2003 Toyota Yaris, used wiper blades an inch bigger than my previous ones. They work a treat - just get a tape measure out quickly, measure your old ones, measure the size of the new ones against your current ones and just do a quick check that it'll fit - an inch or two out from your current ones usually aren't a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

**tl dr:** There is no easy answer here.

Looking through the options on [RockAuto.com](http://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/honda,2005,cr-v,2.4l+l4,1430832,wiper+&+washer,wiper+blade,8852), I see the following:

- Left: 20" or 21"
- Right: 19" or 20"
- Rear: 10", 11", or 12"

I think it really depends on the manufacturer as to what is recommended. The easiest way to know is to go out and measure exactly what you have right now. One caveat is to measure it, then if the size is the smaller option (say the right side is 19" on your vehicle right now), check to see if the larger wiper will fit without issue. *Would it go off of the glass surface at top, bottom, or side?* If it doesn't, consider getting the larger wiper so as to keep more of your glass clean.